# Error testing ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, shoulda

I have a Rails 5.2 app with the following models:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

I'm using rspec-rails (3.7.2), shoulda-matchers (3.1.2).
I have a spec to test the association:

```
describe Foo do
  it { is_expected.to have_many :bars }
  it { should have_many :bars }
end
```

No matter which syntax I use I get the the same error:

```
Foo should have many :bars
Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to have_many :bars }
  expected #<Foo:0x007f9f813ce650> to respond to `has_many?` # ./spec/models/foo_spec.rb:4

Foo should have many :bars
Failure/Error: it { should have_many :bars }
  expected #<Foo:0x007f9f84ad3970> to respond to `has_many?` # ./spec/models/foo_spec.rb:5
```

I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/552#issuecomment-48686578), but still get the error. I have pushed my sample project to Github: https://github.com/fredwillmore/shoulda_matchers_test

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you need to define type of rspec like:

```
RSpec.describe Foo, type: :model do
   it { is_expected.to have_many :bars }
end
```

Comment: I have rspec configured to infer the type from the directory name, so as long as the spec is in a directory called 'models', the type is automatically :model